# Coroutines: launch within runBlocking necessary?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

When I execute:

```
runBlocking {
    launch {
        delay(2000L)
        Log.i(TAG, "World!")
        Log.i(TAG, Thread.currentThread().name)
    }
}
```

Then it results in:

```
... I/myDemo: World!
... I/myDemo: main
... I/myDemo: Hello,
```

When I make "launch" a comment:

```
runBlocking {
    // launch {
        delay(2000L)
        Log.i(TAG, "World!")
        Log.i(TAG, Thread.currentThread().name)
    // }
}
```

Then the result is the same:

```
... I/myDemo: World!
... I/myDemo: main
... I/myDemo: Hello,
```

Obviously starts "runBlocking" a coroutine by itself: [runBlocking Docu](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html)

**Is "launch" necessary at all?**

**What is the meaning/purpose of launch in the first code-example (with no lines as comments)?**

Comment: you didn't include the line of code where `Hello,` is printed.

Comment: Your example lacks the context to determine whether `launch()` is needed or not, but generally speaking it does not make too much sense if there is no code to execute outside of `launch()`.

Comment: @broot Ah, okay. That makes sense. launch starts another coroutine within a coroutine. It might be for cases in which you like to do exactly that. In my specific example it makes no sense. Like I assumed ...

Comment: Yes, `launch()` is for cases when we need to perform multiple operations concurrently. So either we execute multiple code blocks inside separate `launch()` calls or we `launch()` a coroutine and we do something else outside of `launch()`.

Comment: @broot That makes it clear. Thanks a lot.